# GCP Auth Token In Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, oauth-2.0, azure-pipelines

I am facing an error on getting the token from the gcp to azure devops.
I have followed these steps (https://dev.to/ib1/azure-devops-recipe-deploying-google-cloud-function-to-gcp-22l3) using the gcloud command, but the devops cli fails after saying

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I have also tried to add this line in the azure devops yaml script.

```
 gcloud auth application-default login
```

But Now it asks me to go to a link and copy the token. So I did. But Azure pipeline cli doesnt allow me to paste the url anywhere and its continuously waiting. Here is the screenshot.
[link that takes to gcp login and the token but I cant paste token back in azure, because it doesnt ask for any input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeAQm.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error detail, you may miss the step to set .Please refer to doc:[GCP Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#local-key)

for  example:

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\path\to\file\file.json
```

Also, after adding `gcloud auth application login`, Copy the long URL that begins with `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth...` And Paste this URL into the browser of a different, trusted machine that has a web browser.

refer to :[auth login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#run_gcloud_auth_login)

Comment: @Ali Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.